# Shell script with error output using && or ||

Tags: bash, double-quotes

I'm writing a bash code in which I’d like the user to select a folder using zenity. The problem is that if the folder name has some spaces in its name, the selection will fail, but the script will continue (what I don't want).
That is why I tried something to tell the user that something went wrong before exiting the script.

```
inputStr=$(zenity --file-selection --directory "${HOME}")
cd $inputStr || zenity --error --width=300 --height=100 --text "The folder name must not contain spaces." && exit
```

That works when the selection fails. But the fact is that it also exits the script when the selection is fine. I tried replacing «&&» with «||» because I thought I misunderstood something, but that way it runs the code whether the selection fails or not.

Does someone have an idea ?

Comment: Check your script with shellcheck

Comment: See [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88850/precedence-of-the-shell-logical-operators) An alternative solution in your case would be `cd ... || { zenity --error ..."..."; exit; }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In shell, `||` and `&&` have *equal* precedence and are evaluated from left to right in a single list. You are expecting it to be parsed and evaluated as `cd $inputstr || (zenity ... && exit)`, but it's really being evaluated as `(cd $inputstr || zenity ...) && exit`. Thus, your script exits as long as *either* `cd` or `zenity` succeeds, rather than calling `zenity` and exiting if the `cd` fails.

You probably also want to exit even if `zenity`, for any reason, fails: use `;`, not `&&`.

Never mix `&&` and `||` in the same list. Instead, use a proper `if` statement.

```
if ! cd "$inputstr"; then
    zenity ...
    exit
fi
```